# Async web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

Say I have a very simple web service:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class SomeServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public IEnumerable<int> GetSomeDatabaseNumbers()
    {
        return DB.GetMeSomeNumbers();
    }
}
```

The DBGetMeSomeNumbers method does some database retrieval.

I've been reading that the above will cause the request to block while we're waiting for the database to retrieve the data so I'm looking to use the new async features in .net 4.5 to get rid of this blocking issue and handle more requests while we're waiting for the database to get back. I've rewritten by database call like so:

```
public class DB {
    public static async Task<int[]> GetMeSomeNumbers()
    {
        List<int> rtnEntities = new List<int>();
        using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
        {
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT number from SomeTable", sqlConn);
            sqlConn.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sqlRdr = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (sqlRdr.Read())
                {
                    rtnEntities.Add(sqlRdr.GetInt32(0));
                }
                sqlRdr.Close();
            }
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
        return rtnEntities.ToArray();
    }
}
```

How do I modify my Web service call to use this new Async method?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you can remove the `sqlRdr.Close();` and `sqlConn.Close();` lines as those are taken care of automatically by your `using` statements.

Comment: I removed "C#" from your title, since it doesn't matter what language the service is written in - it will have the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it this way:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetSomeDatabaseNumbers()
{
    return await DB.GetMeSomeNumbers();
}
```

Furthermore, I can't see any usages of generic type parameter in `GetMeSomeNumbers<T>`, so I assume you can remove it.

Comment: Ooops, was copying and pasting code. Forgot to remove the generic, thanks.

Comment: What would change if we wrote it this way? (assuming OP corrects his code with `return DB.GetMeSomeNumbers().Result`)

Comment: @L.B, the difference is that when we use `var temp = someTask.Result;` instead of `var temp = await someTask;` it will block the calling thread until the task is completed and ready to return its result. But if you use `await` the thread won't be blocked and could do some other job in the meantime. [1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a340341c-d967-4f56-a2b1-88607092ae2e/taskt-result-vs-await-in-net-45?forum=parallelextensions), [2](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: @Yuriy `... and could do some other job in the meantime` but the web service method *GetSomeDatabaseNumbers* has nothing to do other then waiting the result and return it. It is not an UI  code. It is a server method(handled by its container in a multi-threaded way) which has to evaluate the parameters and return the result.